# Can I open phone app using URL scheme in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Can I open the phone app on iPhone using URL scheme? if yes then how?
I know I can dial a number using this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8004664411"]];
```

But I don't want to dial a number, I just want to open the phone as I click on the phone icon on home page.

Comment: `tel:` URLs don't use "//"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only recognized URL scheme to open the phone app is tel://

There is a nice summary of recognized URL schemes @ <strike>http ://applookup.com/</strike> <- (edit) link is currently spam.

Comment: Hi! The link you've updated doesn't work and I would be really interested on that info. Could you fix the link, please? Cheers!

Comment: Here is a different collection of usable URL schemes, together with some code samples: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 0):

The `tel:` URL will open Phone.app and dial a number.

The documentation is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1

However, there doesn't appear to be a `tel:` URL that simply opens the app. If you provide no number, the `tel:` URL appears to be ignored by iOS.