# how to open phone app in iphone without using "tel://123" url

Tags: objective-c, ios, url-scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I open phone app using url scheme in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699471/can-i-open-phone-app-using-url-scheme-in-iphone)

Within app, I need to launch the phone app. I do not want to dial a call right away like the code below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@\"tel://911\"]];
```

....which would just dial 911. I am wondering if I can just launch the phone app. I tried this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@\"tel://\"]];
```

But it doesnot work

Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. However if you replace `tel:` with `telprompt:` it will prompt the user to confirm the call.

Edit: Also, `@"a string"` is the syntax literal for `NSString`. You shouldn't escape the quotes.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code :-

```
NSString *prefix = (@"tel://123");
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *dialThis = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", prefix];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dialThis];
[app openURL:url];
```

NOTE : Telephone number should be valid format only

Hope it helps you

Comment: From Question : "Within app, I need to launch the phone app. I do not want to dial a call right away like the code" Question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699471/can-i-open-phone-app-using-url-scheme-in-iphone