# Open telephone from the application (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can Someone tell how can I open telephone with a button click? I have used this for safari and it works

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"4167371111";

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]])
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:[phoneNumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
}
```

If you wanted to do something more advanced, like see if the user made the call or not, you can use `CTCallCenter`:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

//Create this property somewhere
@property (strong, nonatomic) CTCallCenter *callCenter;

NSString *phoneNumber = @"4167371111";

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]])
{
    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler: ^(CTCall* call)
     {
         if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected]) {
             NSLog(@"Connected");
         } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing]) {
             NSLog(@"Dialing");
         } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected]) {
             NSLog(@"Disconnected");
         } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming]) {
             NSLog(@"Incoming");
         }
     }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:[phoneNumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
}
```

Comment: [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:[phoneNumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]]; i've an error here "expect identifier"

Comment: Good catch!  There was an extra square bracket on the start of the line. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699471/can-i-open-phone-app-using-url-scheme-in-iphone) SO question.

You can make a phone call using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://0123456789"]];
```

You have to provide a phone number. If there is not a phone number specified:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]];
```

nothing will happen.

The problem with the URL schemes is, that you currently can't open the telephone app. Only starting a call is possible.

Comment: For security reasons Apple made it so the Phone application doesn't support some special characters. They recommend using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on the phone number string if it's not a phone number you've hardcoded yourself into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", @"your-phone-number"]]];
```